# Run localhost server in Google Colab notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to implement Tacotron speech synthesis with Tensorflow in Google Colab using this code form a [repo](https://github.com/keithito/tacotron/) in Github, below is my code and working good till the step of using localhost server, how I can to run a localhost server in a notebook in Google Colab?

My code:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.3.0
import tensorflow as tf
print("You are using Tensorflow",tf.__version__)
!git clone https://github.com/keithito/tacotron.git
cd tacotron
pip install -r requirements.txt
!curl https://data.keithito.com/data/speech/tacotron-20180906.tar.gz | tar xzC /tmp
!python demo_server.py --checkpoint /tmp/tacotron-20180906/model.ckpt #requires localhost
```

Unfortunately running in local mode from Google Colab will not help me because to do this I need to download the data in my machine which are too large.
Below is my last output and here I am supposed to open the `localhost:8888` to complete the work, so as I mentioned before is there any way to run localhost in Google Colaboratory?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using tools like ngrok or remote.it

They give you a URL that you can access from any browser to access your web server running on 8888

Example 1: Tunneling tensorboard running on

```
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

get_ipython().system_raw('tensorboard --logdir /content/trainingdata/objectdetection/ckpt_output/trainingImatges/ --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &')

get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 6006 &')

! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
 "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

Running this install ngrok on colab, and makes a link like http://c11e1b53.ngrok.io/

[Documentaion for NGROK](https://colab.research.google.com/github/shawwn/colab-tricks/blob/master/ngrok-tricks.ipynb#scrollTo=Xr4-BRInUcEB)

Answer (score 5):

Another way of running a publicly accessible server using ngrok:

```
!pip install pyngrok --quiet
from pyngrok import ngrok

# Terminate open tunnels if exist
ngrok.kill()

# Setting the authtoken (optional)
# Get your authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth
NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN = ""
ngrok.set_auth_token(NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN)

# Open an HTTPs tunnel on port 5000 for http://localhost:5000
public_url = ngrok.connect(port="5000", proto="http", options={"bind_tls": True})
print("Tracking URL:", public_url)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use localtunnel to expose the port to the public internet.
Install localtinnel:

```
!npm install -g localtunnel
```

Start localtunnel:

```
!lt --port 8888
```

Navigate to the url it returns to access your web UI.

Answer (score 1):

I did connect my Dockercontainer running a elasticsearch instance on my localhost to google colab with the help of ngrok. Through ngrok you can create a url under which your elasticsearch cluster that runs on your localhost is publicly available (a so called tunnel). I followed [this tutorial](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/).

**First you need to install ngrok.**

For MacOS, use HomeBrew:

```
brew install ngrok/ngrok/ngrok
```

For Linux, use Apt:

```
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null && \
  echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list && \
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install ngrok
```

For Windows, use Chocolatey:

```
choco install ngrok
```

**Then setup ngrok with your Authentification Token**

For this you need to sign-up [here](https://ngrok.com) for a ngrok account. There you will obtain a Authentification Token. Then run the following command

```
ngrok config add-authtoken TOKEN
```

and  replace "TOKEN" with your actual token.

**Now you can start ngrok by running the following command.**

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER
```

Replace "PORTNUMBER" with the port of your localhost you want to connect  to.

Now you should see something like this in your terminal:

```
Session Status                online
Account                       inconshreveable (Plan: Free)
Version                       3.0.0
Region                        United States (us)
Latency                       78ms
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    https://84c5df439d74.ngrok-free.dev -> http://localhost:8000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Now you can use the url provided under 'forwarding' to connect to your localhost.

**Since the whole world can access this URL, we need to secure it quickly.**

Stop your ngrok process (crtl + c) and run:

```
ngrok http PORTNUMBER --basic-auth 'username:password'
```

**Now you can use this URL in google colab to connect to localhost**

In my  google-colab project I connected to a docker container running elasticsearch like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{
        'host': 'c04c-89-128-141-226.ngrok-free.app',
        'port': 443,
        'scheme': 'https',
    }],
    basic_auth=('username', 'password')
)
```

This is just an example and will be different for your usecase obviously.